# Закрыть поток webBrowse.DrawToBitmap

Tags: c#

Загружаю `sfw` в браузер и сохраняю скриншот. Хоть делаю `Dispose` или `GC.Collect()`,  но файл все равно используется процессом. Как принудительно закрыть поток?

```
var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(webBrowser1.Width, webBrowser1.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
webBrowser1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
   webBrowser1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, webBrowser1.Width, webBrowser1.Height));
   bmp.Save(outputDir + "\\" + filename + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
   bmp.Dispose();

});
bmp.Dispose();
```

Comment: Э... Странно. Файл блокируется только внутри `Save`, вызов `Bitmap.Dispose` и уж тем более `GC.Collect` к файлу никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Я хочу удалить файл, но он мне говорит что файл юзается

Comment: Вы абсолютно уверены, что файл блокируется именно вашим приложением, именно последней версией и именно этим кодом?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var bmp = ...
> ```

```
using(var bmp = ...) {
```

А Dispose убери. Оба.